# Is either $\sigma=\tau$ or $\sigma$ is the is the discrete topology ? (True/false)

Tags: general-topology

let $\tau$ be the topology on $\Bbb R$ on which the the interval $[a,b)$, $−\infty< a<\infty$ form a base. Let $\sigma$ be a topology on $\Bbb R$ such that  $\sigma \supseteq \tau$. then

Choose the correct option

1. Either $\sigma=\tau$ or $\sigma$ is the is the discrete topology.
2. If moreover, the map $x \mapsto -x$ is continuous for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is the discrete topology.
3. If moreover, the map $x \mapsto -x$ is a homeomorphism for $\sigma$,  then $\sigma$ is the discrete topology.
4. If moreover ,the map $x \mapsto |x|$  is a homeomorphism for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is the discrete topology

MY attempts; I know that  interval $[a,b)$ is a  Lower-limit topology and it  is strictly coarser than Discrete.
because  in the Discrete topology, every set is open;

But I'm totally struck of this problem, please tell me the solution I would be thankful...

Comment: Note that 1. is not true. Just take $0\in\mathbb{R}$ and define $\lambda$ to be the smallest topology containing $\tau$ and $\{0\}$. This topology is not discrete and properly contains $\tau$.

Comment: My edit was for a trivial typo ("continious").

Answer (score 1):

It's the second.

First of all we see that we can construct a topology $\sigma\supsetneq\tau$ that is not discrete. We do this by noting that $\{0\}\notin \tau$ and by adding $\{0\}$ to the base we get a topology that is still not discrete, yet it's strictly larger.

Now if we take $\phi(x)=-x$ to be continuous this would mean that the inverse image of $[-a,-b)$ that is $(b, a]$ must be open, and since $[a,c)$ is open so is their intersection $\{a\}$. This means that any single-element set is an open set and $\sigma$ is therefore discrete.

---

The 3rd and 4th are also true. The 3rd is obviously so since it implies the 2nd. The 4th is true because the same reasoning leads to that it's discrete on the right halfline and therefore also on the left.

Comment: thanks a lots @ skyking,,,but im not getting  that how their intersection {a} came  ,,,can u pliz elaborate

Comment: @kalomlego I was a little sloppy in the notation (which I've corrected). We then know that $(b,a]$ and $[a,c)$ are both open, then their intersection $(b,a]\cap[a,c)=\{a\}$ must be open (since finite intersection of open sets must be open).

Comment: thanks a lots once again@skyking  im voting up ur answer now

Comment: +1... My edit was on the wording of the last sentence proving that  Option 2 is true : The points are not open, the singletons are. But I have heard pros speak that way.